# multiple simulations in r

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, seq

I am trying to run 1000 simulations from the exponential distribution in R. I hope to get a list of the simulations and a vector of their means. But when I run the code, the first 999 elements of the list are NULL and thus the first 999  means are NAs. what am I doing wrong?

```
nosim <- 1000
n <- 40
r<- 0.2
means<- vector()
sims <- list()
set.seed(4993)
for(i in nosim){
  sims[[i]] = rexp(n, r)
}
means = sapply(sims,mean)
```

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate but I suspect there is no good search term for improper indexing. Should be `for(i in seq.int(nosim)) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your variable `nosim` is a scalar and not an sequence/array.

You should use `seq` (or the faster `seq.int`) instead (as in `seq(1,nosim)`):

```
nosim <- 1000
n <- 40
r<- 0.2
means<- vector()   # not really necessary
sims <- list()
set.seed(4993)
for(i in seq(1,nosim)){    # or use `for(i in seq.int(nosim) ){`
  sims[[i]] = rexp(n, r)
}
means = sapply(sims,mean)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `seq(0,nosim)` would _not_ be correct since you would be sending the first value to the zeroth entry and that does not exist in R. And technically there is no "scalar" data type in R. One uses "length-1 atomic vectors".